# How to add a role into an existing redshift custer in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to add a new role to an existing redshift cluster using CloudFormation.
How Can I add it?

Comment: Are you wanting to modify the CloudFormation template that was used to deploy a CloudFormation stack that started the Redshift cluster? Or are you wanting to create a _different_ template to modify the existing Redshift cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Here are [the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-getting-started-using-spectrum-add-role.html) for a manual change

> To associate an IAM role with a cluster
>
> 1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon Redshift console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/redshift/
> 2. On the navigation menu, choose Clusters, then choose the name of the cluster that you want to update.
> 3. For Actions, choose Manage IAM roles. The IAM roles page appears.
> 4. Either Choose Enter ARN and then enter an ARN or an IAM role, or choose an IAM role from the list. Then choose Add IAM role to add it to the list of Attached IAM roles.
> 5. Choose Done to associate the IAM role with the cluster. The cluster is modified to complete the change.

Via Cloudformation, you would use the `IamRoles` attribute, as outlined [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-redshift-cluster.html#cfn-redshift-cluster-iamroles).